# Cant pop view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 views, `TableController` and `WirelessController`. While in TableController I need to pop the WirelessController view. This is what I've tried and nothing happens, no console output either.

```
WirelessController *wCon = [[WirelessController alloc] init];
[[wCon navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and this has the same problem.

```
[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Is it the fact that I'm using the UINavigationController when it's a view based app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to push, not pop...

```
WirelessController *wCon = [[WirelessController alloc] init];
```

[[self navigationController] pushViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Push adds a new item to the top of the stack; pop removes the top item from the stack.

*Update*

From your comments it seems that...

- your first view is an instance of WirelessController.
- from there you present a TableController modally
- now you want to return to you wirelessController.

In this case you need to send a message back to the *presenting* view controller (wirelessController) asking it to dismiss the view controller it has *presented* (tableController)

In tableController:

```
  [self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                                     completion:nil]];
```

Whatever is going on, you certainly don't want to do this:

```
WirelessController *wCon = [[WirelessController alloc] init];
```

This line will create a new object. You want to return to an existing object.

*Pushing* and *popping* viewControllers is an activity generally associated with navigation controllers, which keep an array of managed viewControllers. In that case you would *push* to add a new controller to the top of the stack, and *pop* to remove it from the stack. In the absence of a navigation controller, there is no such stack, so push and pop make no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to remove `WirelessController` which is placed over the root `TableController`. Pushing `TableController` over everything has the same effect also.

Comment: How did you get to the WirelessController from the TableController?

Comment: What do you mean by a "view based app?"

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller in my storyboard. I call WirelessController via a modal segue

Comment: @verctorquake - Then you don't want to be popping or pushing anything, see my update